# Insert image binary data into table using values keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

```
create table Item(
    ID int identity(1000,1) not null,
    txt varchar(150),
    img varbinary(max),
    constraint pk_Item primary key (ID)
)
```

I can insert an image into this table using the following query:

```
insert into Item(ID,txt,img) 
select 100,'test', BulkColumn from openrowset(bulk N'D:\test.jpeg', single_blob) as image
```

How can I achieve the same using the values keyword:

```
insert into Item(ID,txt,img) values (100,'test',[????])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you want to insert with values keyword when you already have alternative. Try this

```
insert into Item(ID,txt,img) 
values (100,'test',(select BulkColumn from openrowset(bulk N'D:\test.jpeg', single_blob) cs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary values have a 0x{hexdecimal byte sequence} prefix.

```
insert into Item(ID,txt,img) 
values (100,'test',0x0123456789ABCDEF)
```

It might be helpful to just query a field that already has binary value to see what it looks like:

```
select img from Item
```